# Phrasing a sentence

Tags: sentence-patterns, phrasing, paraphrasing

1. In this section, nonlinear effects of two-photon absorption in a photonic crystal cavity are examined.
2. In this section, nonlinear effects of two-photon absorption are examined for a photonic crystal cavity.

First of all, do you find anything unusual or less-than-ideal in either of the two versions above? I think that 2. reads better than 1., since the description of nonlinear effects is so long and the distance between 'nonlinear effects' and the verb 'examined' is quite long as a result. Secondly, do they practically mean the same thing, without any loss or change in meaning? Which would be the more preferred version in writing?

Comment: I know nothing about either *two-photon absorption* or *photonic crystal cavities*, but it seems to me the two sentences mean different things. In #1 it's asserted that the absorption is definitely happening in a cavity (what's being examined are the *non-linear effects* of this process. In #2, something (presumably those effects) is being examined to ascertain whether there is in fact a cavity involved.

Comment: # 1 is more understandable. You are examine the effect in a cavity. I don't think the "for" in # 2 clearly expressed this meaning.

Comment: Ok, so how about this version? "In this section, nonlinear effects of two-photon absorption are examined in a photonic crystal cavity." Does this address the ambiguity issue, and if so, would you say that this is the best version? Or is version 1 still considered best, despite the 'distance' that I talked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of style.  The OP has spotted the problems with his proposed wordings: In sentence 1, an uncomfortably large expanse of words separates the subject and verb; in sentence 2, the verb separates the effects from their location, which are closely related.  The solution is to abandon the scientific passive voice:

> In this section, we examine the nonlinear effects of two-photon absorption in a photonic crystal cavity.

Comment: You don't need to introduce a first-person pronoun (not always encouraged in such contexts). ***This section examines** the nonlinear effects of two-photon absorption in a photonic crystal cavity.*

Answer (score -2):

2. is no good, IMO, because "examined for" could be interpreted as giving a reason.

Think about making the subject less complex by simply moving the "of"-phrase to the end:

> In this section, nonlinear effects are examined of two-photon absorption in a photonic crystal cavity.